# Is there a way to make a input that needs a code to show somthing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website in HTML and for the admin part, I want it to have an input which needs a password to show the admin page.

I tried going to w3schools and tried this code:

```
<button onclick="1()" id="id" >ok</button>
<input id="id2">
```

```
function 2(){
   var x = document.getElementById("thedminpage");
   if (x.innerHTML === "Hello") {
      x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
   } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Hello";
   }
}


function 1() {
  var x, text;


  x = document.getElementById("id2").value;

  // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
  if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  } else {
    run function 2()
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

It didn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: "It didn't work" -- I'm afraid you'll need to provide more information than that. What errors are showing in the console. Note that naming your function `function` is a bad idea, since `function` is a keyword. Also, the code `run function 2()` does nothing good. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems here:

You can't name a function `function()` because it's a keyword of the language.

You can't name a function with a number, maybe you could use `func2()`

You are getting some DOM objects that are not in the HTML code.

Try this:

```
<button onclick="fun2" id="id" >ok</button>
<input id="id2">
<p id='demo'></p>

function func1(){
   var x = document.getElementById("thedminpage");
   if (x.innerHTML === "Hello") {
      x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
   } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Hello";
   }
}


function func2() {
  var x, text;

  x = document.getElementById("id2").value;

  // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
  if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  } else {
    func2();
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```